# Arranging CSS and JS file links (Bootstrap & jQuery)

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm running into problems with various functions that are apparently caused by conflicts between my CSS and/or JS files. If I link to a particular file, one function works, but another stops working or doesn't work the way it's supposed to.

It would probably help if I simply organized the links to these files in a distinct order, like CSS files before JS and Bootstrap files before jQuery files, or vice versa.

Can anyone tell me if there is a proper order I can follow? I'm also updating Bootstrap and jQuery, so I'll probably be linking to some additional files, but I just wondered if there's a general organization scheme I should follow.

```
/css/bootstrap.css
/js/jquery.js
/js/bootstrap.js
/js/jquery.min.js
/css/bootstrap.min.css
/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css
/js/bootstrap.min.js
/fonts/font-awesome-4.5.0/css/font-awesome.css
/fonts/font-awesome-4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css
/fonts/font-awesome-4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css
```

P.S. I always put the links to my personal files AFTER the Bootstrap/jQuery links.

Comment: for starters you have duplicates of most of these...you only need one of each... the `min` ones are minified for smaller size

Comment: Hmmm...that's what I thought. I got thrown off when someone answered a question on StackOverflow with a link to jquery.js and jquery.min.js both. So I thought I had been doing it wrong before. Anyway, I'll go back and delete all the .min links (or vice versa).

Comment: put your CSS `<link>` tags in the head. JS should go at the bottom of `<body>`. Thats not a rigid rule, but I really see no point in mix and matching css with js.

Comment: Would keep  minified for production site and use non minified in development. Put all css in head....then all scripts in body after the html...make sure jQuery loads before plugins and your code after plugins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your header

```
- /css/bootstrap-theme.min.css
- /fonts/font-awesome-4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css
- /css/style.css ( your custom css goes always last to override the rules you want to over-ride)
```

juste before the end of your body

```
- /js/jquery.min.js
- /js/bootstrap.min.js
- /js/myJs.js (your custom js)
```

In the javascript, you always put the dependencies after the master file.
Since bootstrap uses jquery function, jquery has to be loaded before bootstrap. Otherwise, when your browser will read the bootstrap files he's gonna send you errors.

Let me give you an example.

In jquery you have hide() as a method. If bootstrap uses the same method in his js file, hide() must be defined BEFORE bootstrap uses it.

So Jquery is almost always your FIRST js file. 
after that bootstrap for example 
and only as last, your JS files.

Comment: Just 1 extra point- Most of you will need to use popper.min.js... In that case place it after Jquery.min.js & before the bootstrap.min.js!